# How to use button and recycleView together

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

[image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R964AvU-a7TW8Lfp8VqJnmcbvhc-7gcN]

I have a recycleView (see picture). You see there are 2 buttons too. Here's the layout `file.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:background="@color/white">


  <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:id="@+id/main_picture"
      android:layout_width="45dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:src="@drawable/pfl_img"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/main_picture"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Edem Palonik"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:id="@+id/textName"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textDescription"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Profession and ..."
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:id="@+id/textDescription"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textDescription"
        android:id="@+id/historyIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="17/12/2017/13:46"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textDescription"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/historyIcon" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/call_button"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/call_img"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sms_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sms_button"
    android:layout_width="37dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sms_img"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/call_button"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/gray" />
```

I know, I can use `recyclerViewItemCLickListener`, but I wanna click on last 2 buttons separately, so what do I need to do?

So I wanna click on last buttons separately, without clicking all line, I want only last buttons to be clickable.

Here's the java code.

```
public class ConnectionsFragment extends Fragment {
private View mainView;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Connections_item> list;
private Button call, sms;

public ConnectionsFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.connections_fragment, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_connection);
    ConnectionsAdapter adapter = new ConnectionsAdapter(getActivity(), list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    init(mainView);
    return mainView;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Connections_item(R.drawable.pfl_img, "Anun Azganun1", "Inch vor text", R.drawable.missed, "23/11/1998 00:00"));
    list.add(new Connections_item(R.drawable.pfl_img, "Anun Azganun2", "Inch vor text", R.drawable.callagain, "24/11/1998 01:00"));
    list.add(new Connections_item(R.drawable.pfl_img, "Anun Azganun3", "Inch vor text", R.drawable.missed, "25/11/1998 02:00"));


public void init(View v) {
    call = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.call_button);
    sms = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.sms_button);

//        call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Whom you wanna call?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        });

//        sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Whom you wanna send sms?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        });
    }
}
```

Here's the adapter code.

```
public class ConnectionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConnectionsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<Connections_item> list = new ArrayList<>();

public ConnectionsAdapter(Context context, List<Connections_item> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.connections_view_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mainImage.setImageResource(list.get(position).getMainImage());
    holder.fullName.setText(list.get(position).getFullName());
    holder.description.setText(list.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.historyImage.setImageResource(list.get(position).getHistoryIcon());
    holder.date.setText(list.get(position).getDate());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView mainImage, historyImage;
    TextView fullName, description, date;
    Button call, sms;

    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        mainImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.main_picture);
        historyImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.historyIcon);
        fullName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textDescription);
        date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        call = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.call_button);
        sms = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.sms_button);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you tried  clicklistener for particular button ?

Comment: gives nullpointerexception

Comment: post yor java code

Comment: just take this two button in your view holder. initialize there. and in onbindview holder method set click listner

Comment: show the java code

Comment: I added java code.

Comment: Add buttons to viewHolder yes?

Comment: Yes in adapter. that is the error

Comment: add those listeners in adapter

Comment: post your adapter code i will put in that and post answer

Comment: Ok wait a minute.

Comment: I edited the code, and in below i added the buttons too.

Comment: "click in last 2 buttons separately" means in array list last two position button only clickable?

Comment: All works man, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As adapter holds the `recyclerView` item and buttons are in the item
>   so all code related to button will be in the adapter only.

In adapter modify the code :

```
@Override

    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mainImage.setImageResource(list.get(position).getMainImage());
        holder.fullName.setText(list.get(position).getFullName());
        holder.description.setText(list.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.historyImage.setImageResource(list.get(position).getHistoryIcon());
        holder.date.setText(list.get(position).getDate());

        holder.call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Whom you wanna call?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
           });

        holder.sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Whom you wanna send sms?",                                }
            });

    }
```

In java file just remove call and sms button initialization and listners.

Comment: Yeah, 1 seconds ago i done like this too. So in mainActivity am i need write anything else?

Comment: No nothing. all things will be in adapter. As adapter holds the recycler view item and buttons are in the item

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you very very much. I'll accept your answer right now. Please can you vote my question? I need a little reputation)

Comment: Oh no, it says i can only accept this answer after 24 hours(((

Answer (score 5):

Using interface you can achieve this

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Data> mData;
    OnButtonClickListeners onButtonClickListeners;


    public TestAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    public void setOnButtonClickListeners(OnButtonClickListeners listener){
        this.onButtonClickListeners = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        MyViewHolder vh;
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //Bind holder here
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  {


        @Bind(R.id.call_button)
        Button btnCall;

        @Bind(R.id.sms_button)
        Button btnSms;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

            btnCall.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnSms.setOnClickListener(this);


        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(this.onButtonClickListeners!=null){

                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.call_button:
                        onButtonClickListeners.onCallClick(getAdapterPosition());
                        break;
                    case R.id.sms_button:
                        onButtonClickListeners.onSmsClick(getAdapterPosition());
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    public interface OnButtonClickListeners{

        void onCallClick(int position);
        void onSmsClick(int position);
    }

}
```

Then After you can use the call to this interface from Activity and Fragment like below

```
private void setUpRecyclerView(){
        mAdapter = new ProfileAdapter(mContext,new ArrayList<String>());
        lm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rvFeeds.setLayoutManager(lm);
        rvFeeds.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.setOnButtonClickListeners(new OnButtonClickListeners() {
            @Override
            public void onCallClick(int position) {
                    //To do your code here
            }

            @Override
            public void onSmsClick(int position) {
                    //To do your code here
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement onClickListener to the buttons when you are creating the view in the ViewHolder for the recycler view. Then pass an interface with two methods for two buttons and implement the interface in where ever you require.

Like the example:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  public MyViewHolder(View itemView, ButtonClickListener listner) {
    super(itemView);
    Button b1 = itemView.findViewById(...);
    Button b2 = itemView.findViewById(...);

    b1.setOnClickListener(view -> listener.onButton1Click());
    b2.setOnClickListener(view -> listener.onButton2Click());
  }
}
```

And now the interface

```
public interface ButtonClickListener {
  void onButton1Click();
  void onButton2Click();
}
```

Otherwise, if you are accustomed with `bus` you can use instead of using interface. It will make the code much cleaner.

Comment: Why to add so many code, interface and else? I can simply initialize the buttons in holder.

Comment: In my opinion, it provides much more flexibility to handle the data objects. Let's say you are dependent on some other data based on the button click, in that case you need to pass additional data sets to the adapter. Instead if you implement the interface in your activity/ fragment class, it will be easier to handle the data. In another case, if you need to do something on a different thread based on the click, you would prefer activity or fragment class. Moreover, we try to keep our viewholders and adapters as light as possible, so separating the click listeners is better I think.

Comment: Ok thanks, and one more question,  i have no onItemClickListener for recyclerView, how to do this part?

Comment: You can do in the same way I showed. just implement an onClickListener to the entire itemView you are getting in the constructor